# I'm getting an error when I try to install the Amazon MP3 Downloader

Tags: package-management, amazon-mp3-downloader

When I run the .deb file I downloaded from [here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/dmusic/help/amd.html/ref=sv_dmusic_5), I get this error:

`Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libboost-filesystem1.34.1`

Does anyone know a work around for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Amazon MP3 Downloader package is meant for use with 9.04 and depends on some packages that are now out of date. Fortunately, you can download the now-outdated [libboost-filesystem1.34.1 from packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/libboost-filesystem1.34.1) and install it by hand.

If the Amazon .deb gives you further dependency errors, I can help you find those packages as well.

I should mention that there are alternatives to the Amazon MP3 Downloader. [Pymazon](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/pymazon-%E2%80%93-amazon-mp3-download-replacement/) is an option, and [there is now a Banshee extension](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/amazon-mp3-download-extension-for.html) to do the job.

Comment: The Pymazon downloader solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that the version of that package in the lucid repos is:

```
libboost-filesystem1.40.0
```

You can tell by checking for the package on the system. From a terminal run the command:

```
apt-cache search libboost
```

The version is upgraded from the one that the Amazon downloader is looking for. According to the Amazon site, the downloader is compatitlbe with Ubuntu verion 9.04 which is a year old. Are you running a more recent version?

There is a note in this post here: http://blog.binarykatana.com/post/amazon-mp3-downloader-on-lucid/

Note that if you use this you're performing some potentially bad/unsupported actions. Unfortunately the best solution would be for Amazon to better support their download client.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow [the link given by the OP](http://www.amazon.com/gp/dmusic/help/amd.html/ref=sv_dmusic_5), it appears that Amazon has now made official their lack of Linux support for the MP3 Downloader. Their new Cloud Player does have a 'Download' option, though it's not as full-featured as I'd like. You can only download one song at a time, even if you buy the whole album, and it does not give you the nice `[artist]/[album]/...` directory structure that the Downloader did. Still, it's an option.