# Download files from amazon cloud

Tags: 11.10, music, cloud, downloads

I am trying to download music files from amazon as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33158/how-to-download-songs-from-amazons-cloud-player), but in both banshee's amazon mp3 or firefox I am taken to Amazon's page asking me to install it's outdated i386 installer.  I understand banshee >=2.0 can handle these .amz files, so I don't want to [download and install amazon's old binary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2840/im-getting-an-error-when-i-try-to-install-the-amazon-mp3-downloader), but I can't seem to get amazon to let me past this step.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting "download" from amazon's cloud-player, a popup appears that includes a link that says "already have the amazon downloader?"  Clicking this starts the download dialog, and I can select banshee as the program to handle the .amz file, which imports the files successfully.